# How exactly DO you integrate ckeditor with Paperclip so it can upload image files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ckeditor, paperclip

How do you get http://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor working so you can upload image files?  I don't think I'll use the s3 storage...

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. I assume that you have paperclip already set up for S3. So you have only edit the picture.rb and attachement_file.rb in you model directory (app/model/ckeditor/) and replace these lines

```
  has_attached_file :data,
                    :url => "/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename"
```

with your papeclip version has_attached_file:

```
  has_attached_file :data, :styles => { :content => '575>', :thumb => '80x80#' },
    :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml", :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
    :url => ":s3_domain_url"
```

That's it. Btw: this is example from Rails 3.

Comment: This is a standard location by convention? app/model/ckeditor/? There I create which file and put these lines?

Comment: @Agis well, to be honest it should be in lib directory. But I used Ckeditor generator which create this path.

Answer (score 2):

I would follow the [README](https://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor) for the rails-ckeditor plugin you mentioned. If you don't need the SWFUpload, you can simply [integrate the CKEditor and Paperclip](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/uploading-images-with-ckeditor-and-paperclip/), by writing a custom file uploader and custom file browser, and connect them to the editor by specifying urls and callback functions.

It is always useful to have an example, the author has made an [example app](https://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor-demo-app). Unfortunately, there are a few errors in it. Consider the following points to make it running

1. change the following lines in `config/environment.rb`

   `config.gem 'paperclip', :version => '2.3.3'`

   `config.gem 'ckeditor', :version => '3.4.1'`
2. delete the file `index.html` in public
3. add a root route to config/routes.rb

   `map.root :controller => "pages"`

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4.2.0 solution:

> How do you get http://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor working so you can upload image files?

As is, CKEditor allows you to embed existing image URLs, but for CKEditor and Paperclip to work together so you can upload images, you will need ImageMagick. As I understand, it handles uploading the image data, making an image URL reference for the uploaded image data and the embedding of the uploaded image data's URL.

---

## CKEditor

Add `gem "ckeditor"` to your Gemfile

then run the `$ bundle install` command.

---

Add this to /app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require ckeditor/init  <--------------- THIS
//= require_tree . <----------------------- ABOVE THIS
```

---

per: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#how-to-generate-models-to-store-uploaded-files

Add this to:

/config/routes.rb
I put it before the `resources` which utilize it

```
mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
```

---

Using "[form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)" and having set up an "Article" model with a title:string and text:text
/app/views/articles/_form.html.erb

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.cktext_area :text, rows: 10  %> # <-------- "cktext_area"
  </p>
```

Using "[simple_form_for](http://simple-form.plataformatec.com.br)"

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :body, :as => :ckeditor, input_html: {:ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'FULL'}}, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

---

## Paperclip

per: https://richonrails.com/articles/getting-started-with-ckeditor

Add `gem "paperclip"` to your Gemfile and `$ bundle install`.

Then run the following two commands:

`$ rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip`

and

`$ rake db:migrate`

---

## ImageMagick

For macOS Sierra:

```
$ brew install imagemagick
```

For other ImageMagick install options: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php

Answer (score 1):

Use following things it working for me but you should have account on Amazon for s3 storage and correct endpoint you  can refer following

```
code.`gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
gem 'paperclip'

class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset

  AWS_CONFIG = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml")).result)[Rails.env]

  has_attached_file :data,
                    s3_credentials: {
                        access_key_id: AWS_CONFIG['access_key_id'],
                        secret_access_key: AWS_CONFIG['secret_access_key'],
                        bucket: AWS_CONFIG['bucket'],
                    },
                    s3_host_name: 's3.amazonaws.com',
                    :s3_endpoint => 's3.amazonaws.com',
                    storage: :s3,
                    s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
                    s3_protocol:    "https",
                    bucket:         AWS_CONFIG['bucket'],
                    url: ':s3_domain_url',
                    path: '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
                    default_url:   "/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    default_style: "medium"

  validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 2.megabytes
  validates_attachment_presence :data

  def url_content
    url(:content)
  end
end
```

`

comment this line `require "ckeditor/orm/active_record"` from /config/initializers

finally put this line in `<%= f.cktext_area :body %>` view file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Zaparka's response, I had to remove #{Rails.root} as I was getting an unitialized constant error.  SO instead I put "/config/s3.yml", and that worked.