# CKeditor in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

Where I can find my images in rails app folders? I upload them by CKeditor and doesn't know where are they.

```
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin
```

Comment: Which images are you referring to bud?

Do you mean images you put into the editor itself, or images for the buttons on the editor?

Comment: I mean images that I put in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a model to handle the image uploads, typically with the likes of [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

From [CKEditor's Github](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor):

> For files uploading support you need generage models for file storage.
>   Currently supported next backends:
>
> ActiveRecord (paperclip, carrierwave, dragonfly)
>   Mongoid (paperclip, carrierwave, dragonfly)

---

**Image Upload Model**

You'll have a CKEditor model directory (with attachment_file.rb inside) - just add Paperclip options for it. Here's a question which will show you what to do: [How exactly DO you integrate ckeditor with Paperclip so it can upload image files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647905/how-exactly-do-you-integrate-ckeditor-with-paperclip-so-it-can-upload-image-file)

> Yes you can. I assume that you have paperclip already set up for S3.
>   So you have only edit the picture.rb and attachement_file.rb in you
>   model directory (app/model/ckeditor/) and replace these lines
>
> has_attached_file :data,
>                       :url => "/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename",
>                       :path => ":rails_root/public/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename" with
>   your papeclip version has_attached_file:
>
> has_attached_file :data, :styles => { :content => '575>', :thumb =>
>   '80x80#' },
>       :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml", :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
>       :url => ":s3_domain_url" That's it. Btw: this is example from Rails 3.